# Missing Processing Toolbox from QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, toolbox

I'm missing Processing toolbox in my QGIS 3.4 (Mac-version). I know the feature can be activated when going to the Plugins and clicking it on, but it's not there.

Comment: Have you try to reinstall QGIS ? You can install QGIS with OSGeo4W installer or by the independant installer: https://www.qgis.org/fr/site/forusers/download.html

Comment: In QGIS 3 the processing toolbox is in the main menu item "Processing" https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_gui.html#panels-and-toolbars but I suppose that you are missing that as well.

Comment: OH YES, I did reinstall it from here https://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis/ Thank you so much Vincent!!!!! The key was this: OS X security may block installation, as I’m not an “identified developer” (ie not paying Apple to develop software). There a simple way to force it to install – right-click the installer file and select Open, this will trigger an extra option in the security warning to install it anyways.

Comment: Please write that as an answer.

Comment: I believe that the new macOS Qgis versions from the Qgis site are now signed.

Answer (score -1):

This video has definitely helped me. Just few steps to follow.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4g1wnsbpYqQ