# Processing plugin does not exist on Mac

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, mac

I am having a difficult time figuring this out.

I installed the QGIS 3.10 with the all-in-one package, and there was no error during installation.

However, when I open QGIS, I don't see the processing toolbox, and processing does not exist in plugins. By the way, Python console does not exist in the Plugins menu.

How do I solve it?

Comment: Looks similar to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/347508/processing-toolbox-from-qgis