# No processing toolbox in QGIS 3.10

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, qgis-3

I can't find the processing toolbox anywhere in QGIS3.10. I thought I just had to activate it but I can't find it under all plugins or installed plugins. Does anyone know where I can find it or how I can fix this problem? I've attached a picture of the plugin window and the main window.

[image: Plugin window]

[image: Main window]

Comment: related https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/347508/processing-toolbox-from-qgis on installing  right-click the installer file and select Open.

Comment: Thanks, I read that but I installed the official all-in-one version and didn't think it was a problem with that version. I'm now going to try and install the kyngchaos one

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your first screenshot, it seems as if the plugin manager only knows about the core C++ plugins.
This indicates that your QGIS installation has a Python problem.

Some suggest to remove all the Python stuff from your computer and then reinstall QGIS (with Python support).
You could try a web search with `QGIS enable Python support`.

Answer (score 0):

I find it nicely in the plugins:
[image: Processing toolbox]
Maybe you just need to restart QGIS. I tried that.

Comment: This is windows, Hanna is looking for the Mac version.