# Missing processing toolbox in qgis 3.10.3 for mac

Tags: qgis

I am trying to understand the basics of QGIS following their online training manual but I can't find the processing toolbox anywhere in qgis 3.10.3 for mac.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No processing toolbox in QGIS 3.10](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/352845/no-processing-toolbox-in-qgis-3-10)